# failure on building eclipse platform build 'R4_4_maintenance' and latest 'master' branch

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, platform

I am trying to build eclipse platform from the source downloaded from 'git clone -b master --recursive git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git'. 
I have followed this instruction 'http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html#eclipsegerritcontribution_pushconfig' and tried two builds on 'R4_4_maintenance' and 'master' branch.

## Both have got the following failure, anybody knows why? I have build them on ubuntu 13.10 with java 8, maven3.2.1

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tycho-surefire-plugin:0.21.0:test (default-test) @ org.eclipse.ui.monitoring.tests ---
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] {osgi.os=linux, osgi.ws=gtk, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   You requested to install 'bundle org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
```

Comment: Finanlly, I figured it out of the reason of the failure which was caused by maven 3.2.1.  It seems that this building has to use the maven 3.1.1 as stated on eclipse platform web site.